# Flatten 2d-array at compiletime

Tags: c++, c++20, constant-expression

In my code, I need to flatten a two-dimensional `std::array` into a one-dimensional one at compile time. While writing the code I realized, that I am unsure about several aspects of my implementation (as far as readability is concerned). 
Therefore I would really appreciate your input!
I am especially unsure, if

1. There is a more obvious / simpler version in which I can achieve my goal (I previously thought of expanding multiple parameter packs with one `...` or the like)
2. if using a nested lambda is a good idea (I do this in order to obtain access to the parameter pack created by the `integer_sequence` and not expose this API)
3. If using the `requires` expression is really more readable than using a `std::enable_if_t` in this use case
4. and, even if I kind of like my solution to this problem, whether there is a cleaner way of

   1. having automatic template parameter deduction for the "exposed" API
   2. having access to sizes and type of the nested array
5. If there are other things I can improve with my code

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

/// Helper struct, which is std::false_type if the type is not a nested array, and otherwise holds
/// inner and outer array sizes.
template<typename Arr> struct NestedArray : std::false_type{};
template <std::size_t sizeOuter, std::size_t sizeInner, typename T>
struct NestedArray<std::array<std::array<T, sizeInner>, sizeOuter>> : std::true_type{
  static constexpr auto outer = sizeOuter; 
  static constexpr auto inner = sizeInner;
  using type = T;
};

/// Return #nestedArray.flatten()[#index].
template <auto nestedArray, std::size_t index,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<NestedArray<std::decay_t<decltype(nestedArray)>>::value>>
consteval auto getValueByIndex() noexcept {
  using NestedArrayHelper = NestedArray<std::decay_t<decltype(nestedArray)>>;
  constexpr std::size_t innerIndex = index % NestedArrayHelper::inner;
  constexpr std::size_t outerIndex = index / NestedArrayHelper::inner;
  static_assert(NestedArrayHelper::inner > innerIndex &&
                    NestedArrayHelper::outer > outerIndex, "Index out of bounds.");
  return std::get<innerIndex>(std::get<outerIndex>(nestedArray));
}

/// Return 1-dimensional array #nestedArray.flatten() from 2-dimensional array #nestedArray.
/// @param nestedArray:   two-dimensional std::array (std::array<std::array<T, I>, O>)
/// @return               flat representation of #nestedArray (std::array<T, I * O>) with 
///                       nestedArray[o][i] = result[i + I * o]
template <auto nestedArray> 
requires requires() { requires NestedArray<std::decay_t<decltype(nestedArray)>>::value; }
consteval auto flattenNestedArray() noexcept {
  using NestedArrayHelper = NestedArray<std::decay_t<decltype(nestedArray)>>;
  using ContainedType = typename NestedArrayHelper::type;

  constexpr std::size_t flatSize = NestedArrayHelper::outer * NestedArrayHelper::inner;
  return []<std::size_t... ix>(std::index_sequence<ix...>) consteval noexcept {
    return std::array<ContainedType, flatSize> {getValueByIndex<nestedArray, ix>()...};
  }(std::make_index_sequence<flatSize>());
}


// Test, only for demonstrating the purpose of the code. 

/// 2d array 
constexpr std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> arrayOfPairs{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {15, 16}}};

/// Resulting 1d array
constexpr auto flatArray = flattenNestedArray<arrayOfPairs>();

// Test: Print out the resulting 1d array
int main () {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { std::cout << flatArray[i] << " "; } std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I hope that this is appropriate for a Code Review, I linked the code in [compilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Jfy3FD). Note that it can only be compiled with gcc trunk, as clang trunk does not allow std::array as non-type template argument.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm new to CodeReview, and would really like to know what the issues are with my question, so I would really appreciate if you could help me improve the question if you think that there are problems, or that the question does not meet the [reqirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) / isn't on-topic.

Comment: This has gotten a close vote for not working as intended. I can't see why anyone would vote for that. I can possibly see the final paragraph, where you've said which compiler your code works on, could be misinterpreted. But code working in only one interpreter or compiler is not off-topic - I found out the hard way by posting code that targets a single ancient JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: For future readers: the reason the code doesn't compile in Clang is not that the code is wrong, it's because Clang hasn't implemented the C++20 feature

Comment: If you already work with compile time, then isn't it simpler to make a compile-time copy: just make `array<..., x*y>` from `array<array<...,x>,y>` and there is no need for extra class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest readability concern, in my opinion, is squashing everything on one line.  Compare:

> ```
> int main () {
>   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { std::cout << flatArray[i] << " "; } std::cout << std::endl;
> }
> ```

to

```
int main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        std::cout << flatArray[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

which can then be improved to:

```
int main()
{
    for (auto v : flatArray) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

We can use some shorthand to make nested arrays easier to understand:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
    struct multi_array;

    template <typename T>
    struct multi_array<T> {
        using type = T;
    };

    template <typename T, std::size_t Dim, std::size_t... Dims>
    struct multi_array<T, Dim, Dims...> {
        using type = std::array<
            typename multi_array<T, Dims...>::type, Dim
        >;
    };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
using multi_array = typename detail::multi_array<T, Dims...>::type;
```

---

Now, it is more idiomatic to pass the array as an argument instead of a template argument, so that invocation uses more natural syntax and works for both runtime values and compile time values:

```
template <std::copy_­constructible T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
constexpr auto flatten(const multi_array<T, N, M>& array)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
{
    return /* magic */;
}
```

---

We can also easily generalize into multiple dimensions from here:

```
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
    struct multi_array;

    template <typename T>
    struct multi_array<T> {
        using type = T;
    };

    template <typename T, std::size_t Dim, std::size_t... Dims>
    struct multi_array<T, Dim, Dims...> {
        using type = std::array<
            typename multi_array<T, Dims...>::type, Dim
        >;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct multi_array_traits {
        static constexpr std::size_t size{1};
        using type = T;
    };

    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct multi_array_traits<std::array<T, N>> {
        static constexpr std::size_t size{N * multi_array_traits<T>::size};
        using type = typename multi_array_traits<T>::type;
    };

    template <std::size_t I>
    constexpr const auto& get(const auto& scalar) noexcept
    {
        static_assert(I == 0);
        return scalar;
    }

    template <std::size_t I, typename T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr const auto& get(const std::array<T, N>& array) noexcept
    {
        constexpr auto InnerSize = multi_array_traits<T>::size;

        constexpr auto Outer = I / InnerSize;
        constexpr auto Inner = I % InnerSize;

        return detail::get<Inner>(array[Outer]);
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t... Indices>
    constexpr auto flatten(const T& array, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    {
        constexpr auto Size = multi_array_traits<T>::size;
        using Elem = typename multi_array_traits<T>::type;

        return std::array<Elem, Size>{Elem(detail::get<Indices>(array))...};
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
using multi_array = typename detail::multi_array<T, Dims...>::type;

template <std::copy_constructible T>
constexpr auto flatten(const T& array)
{
    constexpr auto Size = detail::multi_array_traits<T>::size;
    return detail::flatten(array, std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pZtBx4))